Cannot Unpickle Document
I have a pretty straightforward dictionary:
{"string1" : ['langchain_core.documents.base.Document', 'langchain_core.documents.base.Document' ...],
"string2"  : ['langchain_core.documents.base.Document', 'langchain_core.documents.base.Document' ...],


I am pickling it in one environment (a databricks environment) and trying to unpickle it in a different environment (a Docker container on my local machine). I am doing this because the databricks environment has bigger compute resources and it allows me to preprocess all of these documents thereby making the operation of my app faster (i.e., the user doesn't have to wait will docs are converted into lists of langchain docs).
I did this for months without problem, and then, now, when I get to that line of my code, it throws an error:
KeyError: '__fields_set__'
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 589, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/src/frontend/pages/Chat.py", line 217, in <module>
    parsed_documents_dict_temp = pickle.load(open(file_path, "rb"))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py", line 417, in __setstate__
    object_setattr(self, '__fields_set__', state['__fields_set__'])

I researched this and the only thing I could find was that either: (i) the pickle changed between pickling and unpickling -- which is not happening; OR (ii) somehow the version of pickle in one environment differs from the version used for unpickling.
To try and deal with (ii) I ensured that both environments are running on Python 3.9.19.  I also confirmed that the pickle version (pickle.format_version) is 4.0 in both the environment that does the pickling and the environment that does the unpickling.
I can confirm that the dictionary that I pickle in the databricks environment, I can unpickle in the databricks environment.  So it's not like the pickle file is corrupt.
I also saw references to PyDantic in some of the posts online, and the error clearly shows that the error is emanating from PyDantic, but I am not using PyDantic to create the dictionary and so I don't know how to satisfy whatever requirement it is looking for.  Is there some way to manually change the state away from ['fields_set']?  I am guessing that is the issue - that Pydantic for whatever reason believes the state is 'fields_set' and so it doesn't think it should unpickle the object?
I also tried using dill, which is supposed to be an extension of pickle, and I get the exact same error.
Any thoughts about how to fix?

The stuff you're unpickling clearly contains some pydantic objects - check that both environments have the same version of Pydantic.

This reads like a case of an XY problem. Can you share a bit on what are you trying to archive in the first place and why you specifically need pickle and what are you pickling exactly?

I think the problem is that I am not sure what the problem is.  That is why I am relaying the error I am getting and the possible solutions that I tried.  It seems like the langchain docs may be triggering the reference to pydantic.  I don't specifically import pydantic.

A common problem is using different Python versions; their pickle formats are not necessarily interchangeable.

I tried running both at 3.9.19 and then I tried both at 3.11.  I have the same problem.
